# Return response messages in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, http-status-codes

I am working with spring boot with a h2 database. I would like to return a 201 message when the register is inserted succesfully and a 400 when is duplicated. I am using ResponseEntity to achieve this, fot example , the next is my create method from the Service:

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createEvent(EventDTO eventDTO) {
        if (eventRepository.findOne(eventDTO.getId()) != null) {
            //THis is a test, I am looking for the correct message
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.IM_USED);
        }
        Actor actor = actorService.createActor(eventDTO.getActor());
        Repo repo = repoService.createRepo(eventDTO.getRepo());
        Event event = new Event(eventDTO.getId(), eventDTO.getType(), actor, repo, createdAt(eventDTO));
        eventRepository.save(event);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/events")
    public ResponseEntity addEvent(@RequestBody EventDTO body) {
        return eventService.createEvent(body);
    }
```

But I'm not getting any message in the browser, I am doing different tests with postman and when I consult for all the events, the result is correct, but each time that I make a post I dont get any message in the browser, I am not pretty sure what is the cause of this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you send post requests from browser ?

Comment: you need `400` for already existing ryt? but you have given `IM_USED` which is `226`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to send Response to the client is to create DTO/DAO with ResponseEntity in Controller

**Controller.java**

```
@PostMapping("/test")
        public ResponseEntity<Object> testApi(@RequestBody User user)
        {
            System.out.println("User: "+user.toString());
            return assetService.testApi(user);
        }
```

**Service.java**

```
public ResponseEntity testApi(User user) {  
        if(user.getId()==1)
            return new ResponseEntity("Created",HttpStatus.CREATED);
        else
            return new ResponseEntity("Used",HttpStatus.IM_USED);   
           // for BAD_REQUEST(400) return new ResponseEntity("Bad Request",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Tested using Postman

**Status 201 Created**
[image: Created]

**Status 226 IM Used** 
[image: Status IMUSED]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I really don't feel good that service sending the `ResponseEntity` but not `Controller`.You could use `@ResponseStatus` and `ExceptionHandler` classes for these cases, like below.

Create a class in `exception` package

#### GlobalExceptionHandler.java

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class) // NOTE : You could create a custom exception class to handle duplications
    public void handleConflict() {
    }
}
```

#### Controller.java

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/events")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) // You don't have to return any object this will take care of the status
public void addEvent(@RequestBody EventDTO body) {
   eventService.createEvent(body);
}
```

Now changing the service would look like,

#### Service.java

```java
@Override
public void createEvent(EventDTO eventDTO) { // No need to return
   if (eventRepository.findOne(eventDTO.getId()) != null) {
        throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("Already exists"); // you have to throw the same exception which you have marked in Handler class
   }
   Actor actor = actorService.createActor(eventDTO.getActor());
   Repo repo = repoService.createRepo(eventDTO.getRepo());
   Event event = new Event(eventDTO.getId(), eventDTO.getType(), actor, repo, createdAt(eventDTO));
   eventRepository.save(event);
}
```